# Get the CurrentBackgroundImage path from an UIImage

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, filepath

Is there a way to get the current image path from an `UIImage`?

For sample, I have a button and I will set the default image on the storyboard but depending on the user language preference, I will get this image and replace for the equivalent from another directory, like: "en-US/imagename.png", "fr-FR/imagename.png"...

I know I could do it, just combining the culture code + image name but I am creating a helper method so I don't have to tell the image name all the time, I just send the object, it reads the current image name and replace it by the new one based on the language culture.

Is there a way to accomplish it, since I have set the first image path in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the UIImage does not keep a reference to it's original source - which may be a file, a stream, etc.